# problem to display plotly gauges converted into images in kivy with image widget

Tags: python, android, kivy, plotly, buildozer

**This is main.py code**

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.image import Image
    from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
    from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    import plotly
    from random import randint
    class MyGrid(Widget):
    img = ObjectProperty(None)

    def test(self):
        fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
            domain={'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
            value=randint(200, 400),
            mode="gauge+number+delta",
            title={'text': "Speed"},
            delta={'reference': 200},
            gauge={'axis': {'range': [None, 500]},
                   'steps': [
                       {'range': [0, 250], 'color': "lightgray"},
                       {'range': [250, 400], 'color': "gray"}],
                   'threshold': {'line': {'color': "red", 'width': 4}, 
                     'thickness': 0.75, 'value': 490}}))

        try:
            fig.write_image("images/fig1.png")

            #with open("images/fig1.png", "wb") as f:
            #   f.write(scope.transform(fig, format="png"))
            #  f.close()
        except:
            pass
        #fig.write_image("images/fig1.png")
        self.img.source = 'images/fig1.png'
        self.img.reload()
        pass



class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        
        return MyGrid()

MyApp().run()
```

This is my KV file

```
 # Filename: my.kv
    #: import Image kivy.uix.image.Image
    #: import Button kivy.uix.button.Button

<MyGrid>:
    img:img
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        #rows:2
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            rows:1
            col_force_default:True
            col_default_width:root.width/2
            row_force_default:True
            row_default_height:root.height*0.4

            Image:
                id:img
                source:'images/fig1.png'
                allow_stretch:True
                keep_ratio:False
            
        Button:
            size_hint:40,None
            text:"reload"
            on_press:root.test()
```

This is working properly when i run in Pycharm, but the same was not working when  it is packaged for android using buildozer.

1. First the error was due to storage permission and it was resolved after lot of searching by adding the following code
   '''
   **in python file**

   from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
   request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
   Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
   **in buildozer spec**
   permissions = WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

'''
after this changes i can access the android storage
2. when run buildozer android debug deploy run logcat, the fig.write_image("images/fig1.png"), is giving permission denied. last 2 days i searched over the internet for solutions and tried different techniques but not successful.
Can anyone please help how to do it correctly, waiting for the answer.

[logcat buildozer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCeAQ.png)

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: @inclement, it is attached at the bottom

Comment: The permission you've been denied is to execute that file, not to read/write something. Probably it isn't executable, that might be lost through the packing/unpacking in the app. Try making it executable via your script before trying to execute it. You can also inspect it to make sure it appears to have the right filesystem properties

Comment: '''from kaleido.scopes.plotly import PlotlyScope
import plotly.graph_objects as go
scope = PlotlyScope()


with open("figure.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(scope.transform(fig, format)'''  \n I tried via the script, although the error was vanished but it generating a blank image file